# Unable to verify access token from Linkedin

Tags: node.js, angular

Using the access token, 
post to the api endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/\~
After this we receive a 401 with the following content:

```
Method: POST:
URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/\~
Error: 
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unable to verify access token",
  "requestId": "C0DUCX81SA",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1421946470523
}
```

Please help me understand or solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

401 means unauthorized request.

And As per error, I think you are not sending the access token.
Please add your code to make me understand more.

**Updated:**

You are sending the token in query and that is what causing you the issue.

LinkedIn doesn't accept the Authentication header and expects a request parameter: **oauth2_access_token**.

Your headers should be like:

```
{
    "oauth2_access_token": "Your_token_here"
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you retrieving the Access Token? Make sure you have followed the steps outlined under https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2.

When making the Authenticated Request to the Profile API, you will need to add the `Authorization` header to your request.

`GET /v1/people/~ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Bearer AQXdSP_W41_UPs5ioT_t8HESyODB4FqbkJ8LrV_5mff4gPODzOYR`

Answer (score -1):

I am sending the access token from client to server by using the XMLHttpRequest

```
 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/' + url);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('token', this.sessionInfo.token);
```

and verifying the token in server side as

```
router.route('/auth/linkedin')
    .post(function verifyLinkedinAccessToken(req, res, Ltoken) {
        var Ltoken = req.headers ['token'];


        // Authorization: Bearer [Ltoken];
        console.log('LinkedIn token from client ==== ', Ltoken);

        var path =  'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=' + Ltoken;
        request(path, function (error, response, body) {
            var data = JSON.stringify(body);
            console.log(data);

            if (!error && response && response.statusCode && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var user = {
                    linkedinUserId: data.id,
                    fullName: data.name
                };
                var jtoken = jwt.sign({ linkedinUserId: data.id }, 'twinesoft', { expiresIn: '3h' });
                res.json(jtoken);  
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.error);
            }
        });
```

After this we receive a 401 with the following content:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unable to verify access token",
  "requestId": "C0DUCX81SA",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1421946470523
}
```